# How to save an image from Google Places API to an ImageField in a Django app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, google-places-api, imagefield

I'm building population code to populate Django model 'City' with images from Google Places API.

This is the model:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='city_pictures')
```

I built the API URL that returns a photo:

```
#fetch image from this url
        city_image_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo'
        '?maxwidth=%s'
        '&photoreference=%s'
        '&key=%s') % (maxwidth, city_image_ref, GoogleKey)
```

Google says the response is a photo and I tested that on Postman so I want to so something like this:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(city_image_url) as response:
            city_image = response
created_city = City.objects.get_or_create(city_id=city_id)[0]
created_city.city_image = city_image 
#plus other fields
```

But I receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\bnbih\Djangos\excurj_proj\population_script.py", line 68, in 
>       populate()
>     File "C:\Users\bnbih\Djangos\excurj_proj\population_script.py", line 64, in populate
>       created_city.save()
>     File "C:\Users\bnbih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 796, in save
>       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>     File "C:\Users\bnbih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 824, in save_base
>       updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>     File "C:\Users\bnbih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 886, in _save_table
>       for f in non_pks]
>     File "C:\Users\bnbih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 886, in 
>       for f in non_pks]
>     File "C:\Users\bnbih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 290, in pre_save
>       if file and not file._committed:
>   AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute '_committed'

I'm using Python 3 and Django 1.10

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile

city_image = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
city_image.write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
city_image.flush()

created_city = City.objects.get_or_create(city_id=city_id)[0]
created_city.city_image = city_image
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3 and Django 1.10. I'm receiving: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delete' AND 'TemporaryFile' object has no attribute '_committed'

Comment: Are you using Windows? If you are using windows, try this: city_image = NamedTemporaryFile()

Answer (score 0):

After following the above answer and [this tutorial](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/dec/03/loading-django-files-from-code/)

This worked for me to save a Google Places image to an ImageField:

**First**, prepare the URL to which HTTP Response is an image:

```
city_image_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo'
        '?maxwidth=%s'
        '&photoreference=%s'
        '&key=%s') % (maxwidth, city_image_ref, GoogleKey)
```

**Second**, retrieve that actual image and save it to a variable:

```
retrieved_image = requests.get(city_image_url)
```

**Third**, create a file locally and write the remote image's content to it:

```
with open(city_names[i] + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(retrieved_image.content)
```

**Fourth**, open the file with the image inside it and convert it to a Django File:

```
reopen = open(city_names[i] + '.jpg', 'rb')
            django_file = File(reopen)
```

**Fifth**, create a model object and save the django file inside the ImageField like this:

```
created_city = City.objects.get_or_create(city_id=city_id)[0]
#save it to the ImageField -> args are: 1. the name of the file that is to be saved in MEDIA_ROOT path 2. The Django file itself 3. save instance
created_city.city_image.save(city_names[i] + '.jpg', django_file, save=True)
created_city.save()
```

Finally, these are the imports you need:

```
from django.core.files import File
import requests
```